# Queryset only allowing me to SELECT just one tables fields in a join

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I have two tables, but am just trying to get just the `dNm` from `T` table (while joining), but instead I can only pull fields from `TSF`.

I have models file:
**models.py**

```
class T(models.Model): 
    emailVerified = models.EmailField(max_length=50) 
    dNm = models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)
    FKToUser = models.ForeignKey('auth.user', default=None, on_delete=models.PROTECT)  

class TSF(models.Model):
    httpResponse = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(3)])
    FKToT = models.ForeignKey('T', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

In regular (pseudo) sql I'm trying to do something like:

```
SELECT dNm
FROM T, TSF
WHERE T.id=TSF.FKToT
AND T.FKToUser=<<THE CURRENTLY SIGNED IN USER>>
```

However, its only allowing me to do the following in pseudo sql:

```
SELECT <any field from TSF>
FROM T, TSF
WHERE T.id=TSF.FKToT
AND T.FKToUser=<<THE CURRENTLY SIGNED IN USER>>
```

My views.py:

```
def viewed(request):
    AUS = TSF.objects.filter(FKToTld__FKToUser=request.user).values('dNm')
    return render(request, 'file.html', {
         'ATFS':ATFSs
    })
```

**Outputting in template**

```
{{ t.dNm }}
```

**UPDATE** This is now not throwing an error on page, but sending a bunch of blanks.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What error? can you post that?

Comment: There is no more error @JPG . It just outputs a bunch of blanks to the template. as if it found the  records, but it isnt outputting a value. Likely the same value over an over, but with nothing there. I just need unique values (think `SELECT DISTINCT`)

Comment: Your view code defines a variable named `AUS`, then pass an undefined `ATFSs` variable to the context, then in your template you use `{{ t.dNm }}` but `t` isn't defined anywhere.  If you expect any sensible answer, post a sensible question with sensible code example.

Comment: Also, all this is fully documented, **as I already mentionned in a comment in your previous question** (with a link to the doc). You are supposed to first search the topic by yourself (which of course includes reading the documentation) before posting here, and you obviously didn't bothered to, neither last time nor this time. Basically, you're asking us to read the doc for you, which is very rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values()` returns a Queryset of dictionaries. you can check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) for more info.

You can do something like this:

**views.py**

```py
AUS = TSF.objects.filter(FKToTld__FKToUser=request.user).values('FKToTld__dNm').disctinct()
```

**template.html**

```html
{% for key, value in ATFS.items %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is now not sending an error, but sending a bunch of blanks to the template . see how im outputting in a template above